# Please guide about this error how i can solve it.Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, console-application

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than
> the size of the argument list.

I want to print all strings using one `Console.WriteLine()` method.

````
Student stdnt = new Student();
Console.WriteLine("\n{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}", stdnt.full_name, stdnt.course, stdnt.subject, stdnt.university, stdnt.e_mail, stdnt.phone);
Console.ReadKey();```
````

Comment: Please refer to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation). It details c# placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 6 inputs but 7 placeholders:

```
Console.WriteLine("\n{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}", 
stdnt.full_name, // 0
stdnt.course, // 1
stdnt.subject, // 2
stdnt.university, // 3
stdnt.e_mail, // 4
stdnt.phone);// 5
// No 6
```

However, this is better:

```
// Note the $
Console.WriteLine($"\n{stdnt.full_name}\n{stdnt.course}\n{stdnt.subject}\n{stdnt.university}\n{stdnt.e_mail}\n{stdnt.phone}");
```

Please see [String interpolation in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation).

Answer (score 0):

just remove \n{6} from your code;
you have 6 property in your instance and try to print 7 property

Answer (score 0):

if the String.Format confuses you in such cases and if you don't want to using ($)

alternative

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("\n", String.Join("\n", stdnt.full_name, stdnt.course, ...))
```